# Redigo ScanStruct error with time.Time

Tags: go, redis

I am trying to read a struct that has a field of type `time.Time` using redigo's ScanStruct, which gives me the following error: `cannot convert from Redis bulk string to time.Time`.

Is the only way of fixing this to create my own `time` type that extends `time.Time` and implements `RedisScan`? That sounds bad as well...

Comment: What's so bad about implementing a method to parse the time format you expect?

Comment: If you show the larger problem you are trying to solve, we may be able to provide some advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Redis has no concept of time values it would make no sense for a generic driver such as redigo to perform some automatic conversion between the builin `time.Time` type and an arbitrary byte array. As such, it's up to the programmer to decide how to perform that conversion.

For example, supposing you have a "Person" type defined as such, including a `created_at` timestamp formatted as [RFC3339 (a form of ISO 8601)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), you could define a custom "Timestamp" type with a "RedisScan" method as follows:

```
type Timestamp time.Time

type Person struct {
  Id        int       `redis:"id"`
  Name      string    `redis:"name"`
  CreatedAt Timestamp `redis:"created_at"`
}

func (t *Timestamp) RedisScan(x interface{}) error {
  bs, ok := x.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return fmt.Errorf("expected []byte, got %T", x)
  }
  tt, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, string(bs))
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  *t = Timestamp(tt)
  return nil
}

// ...

response, err := redis.Values(conn.Do("HGETALL", "person:1"))
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

var p Person
err = redis.ScanStruct(response, &p)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
log.Printf("OK: p=%v", p)
```