# Constructing custom type of time.Time by providing values returns not expected values

Tags: go, redis

I'm implementing a method **RedisScan(...)** by following this SO answer [Redigo ScanStruct error with time.Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897965/redigo-scanstruct-error-with-time-time).

My method:

```golang
func (t *Timestamp) RedisScan(x interface{}) error {
    bs, ok := x.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected []byte but got %T", x)
    }

    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
    parsedTime, err := time.Parse(layout, string(bs))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    } 
    fmt.Println(parsedTime) // 2019-12-10 00:00:00 +0000 UCT
    fmt.Println(Timestamp(parsedTime)) // some gibberish....

    *t = Timestamp(parsedTime)

    return nil
}
```

and here's my custom type `type Timestamp time.Time`

The issue is that when I print out **parsedTime** inside my RedisScan method, it outputs **2019-12-10 00:00:00 +0000 UCT**. But printing out **Timestamp(parsedTime)** outputs **{0 63714211200 0xc0001591a0}**. Can someone explain me what's going on here?

Comment: It's because `time.Time` implements the `fmt.Stringer` method, but your custom type doesn't. It would be better to embed `time.Time` in your type: `type Timestamp struct { time.Time }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would expect to see. Time.Time implements fmt.Stringer (see [string()](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go?s=14552:14581#L440))  which the various fmt functions will call (if the interface has been implemented). Your Timestamp type does not implement this so the raw struct is dumped.

Time.Time is defined as :

```
type Time struct {
    wall uint64
    ext  int64
    loc *Location
}
```

and these are the three values you are seeing.

To fix this you could uyse something like `fmt.Println(time.Time(parsedTime).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"))`, implement String() in Timestamp or [embed time.Time](https://play.golang.org/p/FlgJREW_8yk) into your struct.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! Your embed solution works and it makes sense!

Comment: A much better way to "fix" it is to embed `time.Time` in the custom type instead:  `type Timestamp struct { time.Time }`. Then the pre-defined functions are accessible.

Comment: @Flimzy - that is the third option I provided "or embed time.Time into your struct" (includes link to the playground demonstrating the approach). Not sure if the downvote is from you but if so please reconsider.